# Condensation forming on garage roof despite insulation

Tags: insulation, roof, garage, condensation

I have a condensation problem on the inside of my garage roof. I noticed it in November, lots of condensation forming on the roof but only at the back half of the garage which is slowly being converted into a utility room. This hasn’t been a problem before, my only thought was maybe the tumble dryer was causing the problem as it is also located in the same area. I decided to buy some foam insulation at 75mm thickness as the void between the wooden beams and the garage roof was roughly 150mm therefore I knew using 75mm would leave another 75mm air gap between the insulation and roof. I did the job using foil tape to seal all joints and even spray foam in small gaps but make everything as air tight as possible.

Today I decided to check the roof, running along side the garage is a full length passage way that has the same flat roof as the garage and I didn’t insulate this part as I wanted to inspect the garage roof over the utility room for more condensation. To my horror it is probably worse now. Water drops are dropping onto the foil back foam insulation with more condensation forming on the roof. It’s also so cold in there at the moment that some of the water is turning to ice. I can only assume one of two things is the reason. 1.) I need to also insulate the passage way too or 2.) some how the tumble dryer is still managing to penetrate through the insulation and create condensation. I’m slightly at a loss here. I’m not a great DIYer but will do what I can to sort this issue if anyone has any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To clarify, is there an attic above the garage that you added insulation to? If so, what sort of ventilation does the attic have?

Comment: What does the venting of your roof look like?  Do you have a soffit and/or a ridge vent?  Leaving the gap between the insulating panel and the roof (as recommended) doesn't do much if you don't have good air circulation between the foam panels and the roof.

Comment: @izzy there is nothing above the garage roof. It’s a 18month old flat garage roof with rubber epdm fitted.

Comment: @SteveSh no vents that I know of. It’s a single brick garage (connected to the neighbours garage)

Comment: If there's no venting you've essentially sealed the space. Moisture will evaporate and condense as temperature changes. You might remedy the situation somewhat with some desiccant, but chances are the problem will persist until you vent the space.

Comment: @isherwood how do I go about venting? Would a simple extraction fan in the back wall of the utility room suffice? Problem is won’t I need to vent in between each row of joists?

Comment: Yes, we're talking about the unconditioned space, not your rooms. I can't say from what I can see.

Comment: Pictures added of outside of garage

Comment: IMO, you've made things worst by partially creating an encapsulated air space.  You might be able to help the situation if you can attach the insulating panels directly to the bottom of the roof and eliminate any air space between the panels and the roof.  On the other had, that could just hide the problem even more.

Comment: Is your dryer vented properly? Don’t use those dryer vent heat savers they just pump wet air into the house and make problem of condensation worse. I have only seen this bad of problems with metal roofs do you have metal over the OSB?

Comment: @isherwood photos are too big so I have to link them.

Comment: @SteveSh I’ve come across something called “roof breather vent” designed to be fitted to the outside of a rubber roof to allow ventilation in the void above the insulation. Hopefully they can be fitted to existing rubber roofs

Comment: @EdBeal it’s a condensing dryer unfortunately, there is nothing over the OSB simply the OSB and then the epdm rubber covering.

Comment: Ok I would make sure your coils are very clean after picking up a good sized dehumidifier, condensing dryers if not clean pump quite a bit of moisture into the air and that is the root problem. Eliminate the airborne water in that area snd the roof will no longer sweat.

Comment: Condensing dryers are fine if they actually work properly.  They shouldn't have any exhaust gases at all.  The only reason dryers have exhaust is to eject water vapor and natural gas combustion products.  A condensing dryer doesn't need to do either one.

Answer (score 1):

The principle at work here is basically this: condensation, or dew, forms when humid air is exposed to a cold surface. More specifically, it forms on a surface when the temperature of the surface is below the dew point of the air. It's the same thing that happens when droplets form on the outside of a glass holding an ice-cold beverage.

One way to prevent the condensation forming is to keep the air-exposed surface warmer. Obviously the exterior of the roof is simply going to get cold in winter; there's nothing to do about that. What one can do, though, is apply vapor-impermeable insulation to the interior side of the roof deck and keep the interior space warm. "Vapor impermeable insulation" often translates to "closed-cell spray foam." With this foam applied the water vapor in the air can reach the foam's surface but can't permeate deeper into the roof assembly. The foam's surface is warmed above the dew point by heat from the room and condensation is prevented.

The other (and more common) way to prevent condensation is to control the dew point. This is done by controlling the relative humidity, which in turn means controlling sources of water vapor and venting whatever vapor is created. This is why we often use layers in exterior walls and roofs:

- interior wall finish
- vapor barrier
- insulation
- exterior wall substrate
- exterior wall cladding

The vapor barrier prevents (slows) diffusion of water vapor into the insulation. If it were absent then vapor would condense *in* the insulation -- or, if the insulation were absent too, then the vapor would condense on the wall substrate.

The foil facing on your insulation should be a good vapor barrier especially because you've taped the joints. Somehow, though, vapor is getting around the barrier. Maybe you can improve this.

When you've done all you can to control vapor sources and to establish a vapor barrier, then next defense is to ventilate the roof/attic space to exhaust whatever vapor gets in there.

Comment: Great answer I regularly use and recommend dehumidifiers. In places like a workshop that is only heated on weekends I suggest foam.

Comment: How about adding insulation on top of the roof during re-roofing? Work underside seems a lot of work and still may have the same problem. Even with a small imperfection, moist air would accumulate with nowhere to escape.